# Apache HTTP to HTTPS redirect, absolute links and bookmarks fail

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, redirect

I obtained some proper SSL certificates for our website.
I was able to get them installed and tests of the HTTPS side worked great.
The only thing left was to redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS, and then things went to crap.

I added the following line to my `<VirtualHost *:80>` area:

```
Redirect permanent / https://www.website.com/
```

This caused some interesting behavior in two ways. The first is that all absolute links within the website to a different directory within the website failed. For example a link to `http://www.website.com/directory` would end up at `https://www.website.comdirectory` with the obligatory "This site can’t be reached" error. Directly entering in the URL `http://www.website.com/directory` would give the same behavior.

Would it be better to replace the Redirect statement with this?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/%$1 [R,L]
```

Or is something else needed?

Comment: Your redirect and rewriterule do exactly the same thing. What you describe is almost always caused by mismatching trailing slashes in redirects or rewriterules. Can you check your http to https redirect and make sure it's as you posted (i.e. check the target URL has the trailing slash)? Otherwise it seems likely there is another redirect/rewriterule you don't know about.

Comment: There are 4 other Redirect statements in some of the other conf files. They all look similar to this: `Redirect permanent /ftp/EMF /emf`. None of them include the directory that I have been testing with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we figured this out.

Because there are multiple config files, each one for a different mounted directory, every one of those config files needed a redirect rule or rewrite rule set.

Now that said rules are in place the website works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.my-site.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using .htaccess. Will this work in my .conf file? I tried it but the configtest failed saying `RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters`.

Comment: Maybe try it without the [R, L] ?

Comment: With or without the `[R, L]`, or just removing the space within, the problem was the same.

Comment: Yeah -- the space should have been removed. I have fixed my comment to reflect the correct syntax. When you run the line in [www.htaccesscheck.com](http://www.htaccesscheck.com/) the syntax checks out okay without  the space, but with the space it does throw the warning you mentioned. You might check your string at this URL to make sure you don't have a typo you're missing or something.

Comment: I found it -- the underscore was missing from SERVER_PORT -- try it as written above now.

Comment: Well the configtest passed it but this still did not help the problem.

Comment: What are you using for an index file? index.php?

Comment: Try this:
`DirectoryIndex index.php`

Comment: For the most part the index files are html. But please reread the initial problem. The issue is with the redirect removing a `/`, not with the index file not loading.

Comment: Sorry -- I thought the missing slash was a typo rather than the root of the problem -- is there anything at all in .htaccess? There has to be another rule somewhere causing this.